# Third-party library into iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used a lot of third party libraries in my code, for example, `AFNetworking` for the networking, and `Rapture XML` for parsing the XML on iOS.

Now my question is:

If I use these third-party libraries in an app that I develop and publish on the App Store, will Apple approve my app or reject it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you should be fine, with one caveat: some third-party libraries are written by amateurs and use private API calls. If those libraries are distributed as precompiled object files and not as raw source, you may find your app rejected by Apple's private API verification tools, but be unable to find any instances of the forbidden API calls in your source.

Answer (score 1):

In short No.

You can use third party libraries as long as they don't use private api, and for this two you can be sure not be bothered by Apple.

You can check technically your app in the Organizer that come with Xcode (just archive your app, and then check Validate) for private api usage.